# How to stop a selenium executable compiled with nuitka standalone and onefile executable from launching webdriver terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I've built a script where it launches selenium in headless mode and shows some data on a GUI made with tkinter. But when I compile it, it launches a webdriver terminal and I can't seem to find a solution for this anywhere.

The command I used:

```
nuitka --onefile --windows-icon-from-ico=./assets/Icon.ico --plugin-enable=tk-inter --include-data-file=./assets/notification.mp3=. --include-package-data=selenium --mingw64 --standalone --disable-console Testpy
```

As for the webdriver, I'm using it like this in my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=cls.options)
```

I haven't tried using webdriver-manager yet because it takes a lot of time to compile because my pc isn't as good and I can't to compile it again and again.

I've been looking around for a while but found absolutely nothing regarding this issue.

I've tried a bunch of nuitka arguments but none of them seem to work and I have lost count of what I tried at this point. I had tried using pyinstaller and it's pretty much the same. I think its something to do with webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

For Selenium version 4.12, in addition to running in headless mode you can use creation flags to force the program to not open any windows.

```
chrome_service.creation_flags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```

You can then disable logging (which is probably what is causing the terminal to open) by using log_output = os.devnull

Here was my code for Firefox that did not open any windows/terminal:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")

service = FirefoxService(log_output=os.devnull)
service.creation_flags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service, options=options)
```